# where does the error "no such table" come from?

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm stuck with my code and i would love having help!

Here is my code :

---

```
import sqlite3


def ajout_consultation(id_date, code, matricule, numero_ss):
    #relie le code sql au code python
    connexion = sqlite3.connect ('cabinet_medical_original')
    curseur = connexion.cursor()
    #permet d'utiliser des clefs etrangères
    curseur.execute('PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON')

    nv_consultation = (id_date, code, matricule, numero_ss)
    nv_consultation = ('2023-12-07', 2, 1, 12)
    curseur.execute('INSERT INTO Consultation(id_date, code, matricule, numero_ss) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)', nv_consultation)
connexion.commit()

#déconnexion
curseur.close()
connexion.close()


ajout_consultation('2023-12-07', 2, 1, 'stephanie')
```

---

the respond that i got is:
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: Consultation

i can't manage to find the problem

i have looked on bd browser and "Consultation" exist and when i try to add a consultation from there i got : FOREIGN KEY constraint failed,
the two are in the same file

if some have an idea why it doesn't work i would love to know,
thank you!

Comment: 99% sure the issue is with line  `connexion = sqlite3.connect ('cabinet_medical_original')`.. Use a absolute path the file.

Comment: Check you indention, hopefully only on your question is this failure! How looks like you table definition?